# A strange issue or bug with initializing CGSize

Tags: swift

I am defining and then initializing an optional CGSize type value in 2 deferent way, I expect that in both case I should have an optional size after all, but strangely, in way 1 even after feeding width and height, the value is still nil! Am I missing something in here?

```
var value1: CGSize? = nil
value1?.width = 100.0
value1?.height = 100.0
print(value1)                                   // print: nil


var value2: CGSize? = nil
value2 = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
print(value2)                                  // print: Optional((100.0, 100.0))
```

Comment: optional chaining is failing silently. The solution is to do not declare it as optional and set `.zero` as its initial value

Comment: hi swiftPunk.  **don't use optionals**.    what Leo is saying is do this:  `var value: CGSize = .zero`   notice there IS NOT question mark after the type, CGSize.  in general simply NEVER use optionals (that's the "?") until you really need to.

Comment: it's important to realize your second example **is also very wrong**.  other than in extremely obscure, totally unrelated situations, you would never make the type of value2 `CGSize?`.  you'd just be fired if you did that on a team. `CGSize` is totally different from `CGSize?` and what you want here is `CGSize`.

Comment: @Fattie: I got confused, why way 2 is also bad idea?! I mean if we wanted optional CGSize way 2 would be a way, or do you have better way for optional CGSize?

Comment: @swiftPunk Why would you need to declare size as optional? Why don't you simply initialize it with `.zero`? As I have already mentioned if you really need to assign nil to your size just don't use optional chaining

Comment: @LeoDabus: one of use case: **@inlinable public func frame(width: CGFloat? = nil, height: CGFloat? = nil, alignment: Alignment = .center) -> some View**

Comment: Why would you pass a height and not a width or vice-versa? Is there any problem using `.zero` instead of `nil`? `width: CGFloat = .zero`

Comment: I know what you mean, but in some case we have to start with nil, if we got zero value for size some calculation would we happen with value zero which I do not want, making optional, make sure we got the right value to work, that is the why i need optional and not zero, because zero could be part of calculation later but not on lunch time

Comment: What I meant is that you can check if the size is zero the same way you check if the size is nil.

Comment: yeah, you right that is also an option, not bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you're telling it to do.
You never initialize value 1, so your optional chaining is failing.

if you wanted to set width and height and get a CGSize, you would need to initialize it and then set its values:

```
var value3: CGSize? = nil
value3 = CGSize()
value3?.width = 100.0
value3?.height = 100.0
print(value3)       //Optional((100.0, 100.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over the first example:

```
var value1: CGSize? = nil
```

Ok, so `value1` is currently nil.

---

```
value1?.width = 100.0
```

What you're doing with `?` is called [optional chaining](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html). This makes it so that if `value1` is **not nil**, then set `width` to 100.

But `value1` is still nil.

---

```
value1?.height = 100.0
```

Same here. It's still nil, so it doesn't set `height` either.

---

```
print(value1)
```

`value1` is still nil, so `nil` is printed.